# Construction of Elliptic Curve with given $j$-invariant

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Recall the following well-known result. Let $K$ be a number field, and let $j_0 \in \overline{K} \setminus \{1728\}$. Then there is an elliptic curve defined over the field $K(j_0)$ with $j$-invariant equal to $j_0$, and in the affine plane, one such curve can be thought of as being cut out by the Weierstrass equation
$$y^2 + xy = x^3 - \frac{36}{j_0 - 1728} x - \frac{1}{j_0 - 1728}.$$
It is easy to check that the $j$-invariant associated to the above Weierstrass equation is in fact $j_0$, but how does one actually derive this formula without knowing the answer? Or did mathematicians just stumble on it?

Comment: The parametrization by the Weierstrass function $\wp_\tau$ gives naturally an universal elliptic curve and with a change of variable $(x,y) \mapsto (u^2 x, u^3 y)$ it becomes $y^2 = x^3-\frac{27j}{j-1728}x-\frac{27j}{j-1728}$ which makes it clear the field $\mathbb{Q}(j)$ can be chosen as the field of definition

Comment: @reuns Thanks!!